# Query to Insert Category data based on other tables

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010

So I am using a access (sadly) to drive a vb program to register students to classes.  I have three tables register, students, and courses.

[image]

I would like to added the student Id and course Id as relationships in the register table. 
It was a long time since I did SQL so I failed horribly the first time:

```
INSERT students.id INTO register.studentid WHERE 1 = students.id 
INSERT courses.id INTO register.courseid WHERE '12345' = courses.crn
```

The use of INSERT INTO was wrong. However,  can you do something like:

```
INSERT INTO register (studentid, courseid) VALUES (1 = students.id, '12345' = courses.crn);
```

because my current VB codes works something like:

```
If Not TextBox1.Equals("") Then

        query += "INSERT students.id INTO register.studentid WHERE '" & StudentID & "' = students.id "
        query += "INSERT courses.id INTO register.courseid WHERE '" & TextBox1.Text & "' = courses.crn"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement should be in the following format

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)
```

So, what you are looking for is something like:

```
INSERT INTO register (studentid, courseid) VALUES (1, '12345')
```

AND

```
If Not TextBox1.Equals("") Then
    query += "INSERT INTO register (studentid, courseid) VALUES (" & StudentID & ", '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
End If
```

Here is an [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/855cc/11/2) example you can play with.

Comment: okay, then how can I query to find the respective course.id where the course course.crn is 12345

Comment: Can you nest that can you? INSERT INTO register (studentid, courseid) VALUES (SELECT ID FROM courses WHERE crn = '12345', SELECT course.id FROM courses WHERE crn = '12345'

Comment: No, your INSERT statement doesn't make any sense. You are selecting the course id and inserting it into the studentid field of register. I don't understand why you would want to do that. I did update my answer with a SQL Fiddle example that you can work with. It is in SQL Server but can be translated easily to MS Access.

Comment: I would like to insert the course id as where the crn is equal to 12345.  my thinking was since the primary column was the id, then I would use that.  But i guess I could use just the crn as the relationship.